# Is it possible to get match information, for instance, the score, from valve servers (eg. Dota2/CS:GO)

Tags: modding

I've been searching for information but couldn't find any. I don't even know if this is the appropiate place to ask. If it's not, please delete the question and forget me.

I'd like to know if there is an API or something that lets me petition a server where a match is being played, and retrieve the current score or some other information regarding that match.

I am interested in Counter Strike: Global Offensive matches, for instance.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/webapi Results of a quick search, there will likely be a better answer but this should be your starting point.

Comment: http://dotabuff.com -- uses DOTA2 data if you expose it publically

Comment: I think how to interact with existing games should be asked on the forums related to the games you're asking about.